# nginx-ingress controller doesn't do round robin

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am new to the Kubernetes cluster and trying to setup my very first kubernetes cluster and very first load balanced service.
I have a hybrid environment which contains two Windows and two CentOS nodes + 1 CentOs Master node

As far as Kubernetes goes, everything is working fine. I deployed nginx-ingress controller as daemon set which runs only on Linux servers. I followed the following tutorial:
https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md with only one difference that in deployments/deployment/nginx-ingress.yml, I restricted to run it on Linux machines using nodeselector

I created a deployment with 2 replicas and service for the deployment. I also created ingress resource But when I create a service, it always goes to Pod on one node. Here is my code:

**Service and Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice-1
  labels:
    app: myservice-1
spec:
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 9034
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: myservice-1 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myservice-1
  name: myservice-1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myservice-1
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myservice-1
        run: with-creds        
      name: myservice-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myservice-1
        securityContext:
          windowsOptions:
            gmsaCredentialSpecName: gmsa-dev-credspec
        image: secure-myprivaterepo:443/docker/library/myservice-1        
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: windows
```

And here is my ingress resource

**Ingress Resource:**

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myservice-1-ingress  
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myservice1
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: myservice-1
              servicePort: 9034
```

I see that both my replicas are working no two different Windows node. 
I use HAProxy to roundrobin the request to my two Linux nodes so that it can hit the nginx-ingress controller running on those nodes. From logs, I can see that request is being routed to both of these servers in (kind of) round robin fashion. Here is my HAProxy config.

**HAProxy front end and backend config**

[image: HAProxy front end and backend config]

**HA Proxy Defaults:**

[image: HA Proxy Defaults]

**More Details (requested by PjoterS):**

- CNI Used: Flannel (I used documentation on Microsoft site to configure Flannel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/network-topologies) and used host-gw configuration
- I have used the following document from Microsoft
  to join my windows node to my Kubernetes cluster:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/joining-windows-workers?tabs=ManagementIP#joining-a-flannel-cluster
- I have used kubeadm on bare metal CentOS machines to create a cluster
- I can't ping From one pod to another pod living on different nodes
  [image: Ping from one pod to other]
- Pods are not scheduled on Linux node so I can't curl to my Windows node. These are Windows Full Framework (mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet) images and can't be scheduled on Linux servers
- Out of curiosity, I scaled my deployment up to 4 replicas so each of my two windows servers can get two pods. Now when I ping one pod on to another on the same node, ping works just fine. So It seems that pods on different nodes can't be reached by each other.

**Problem:**

I made a host entry currently in my local machine pointing to my HAProxy iP and visit site http://myservice1 and my windows service is working fine but when I exec to each pod and look at the application log, I see that log is generated on just one pod and pod on the other node hasn't even being called once. I tried more than 100 requests and every time, node 1 responded and node 2 is not invoked at all.

Do I have to do anything specific so that ingress controller really forwards traffic in round robin fashion? I tried searching on blogs but hasn't find any answers at all

Comment: Could you provide more information about your Network configuration, what CNI are you using? How did you add those nodes (based on this doc? https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/windows/user-guide-windows-nodes/)? It's On-Prem or Kubeadm? Are you able to reach other pods internally? Can a pod scheduled in a linux node curl another in a windows node and viceversa?

Comment: PjoterS, I added More details section to my original question. Please let me know if I am missing something. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you follow steps? : 
`After running this you should be able to:`
View joined Windows nodes using kubectl get nodes
See 3 powershell windows open, one for kubelet, one for flanneld, and another for kube-proxy
See host-agent processes for flanneld, kubelet, and kube-proxy running on the node

Could you provide output of `kubectl get nodes`

Comment: was this solved? @AndyJohnson maybe you feel like sharing the solution with the community?